# Matlab: Gradient and Hessian of a function with vector input of user specified size

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

I need to write a matlab m file that takes the following function of $x=(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{2n})$, and for $n=10$, $n=100$, $n=500$, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(x_{i})^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}x_{i}+\sum_{i=2}^{2n}\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(x_{i}+x_{i-1} \right)^{2} +\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)^{2}\right]+\left(x_{2n}-x_{1} \right)^{2} $$ calculates the gradient, and each component $H_{ij}=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}$ of the Hessian matrix.

Now, the course that I am doing this for is NOT a course on Matlab (its a nonlinear optimization course). In fact, they take for granted that we all are extremely proficient in Matlab and are comfortable programming to this sophisticated of a degree, which I am not.

Therefore, I am asking, based on the code that I have done thus far, which I am including in a grapic, how do I write the code to

1. Calculate the gradients, based on the number inputted into the function by the user, and put all the components into a function of the form $g = [\cdots; \cdots; \cdots]$ with $m$ components.
2. Calculate the Hessian components, also based on the number inputted into the function by the user. **EDIT:** I think I might have come up with suitable code for this. Please see my screenshot and tell me if it looks okay. (Still have no idea how to do this for the gradient though)

I am assuming I would need to set up some kind of dynamic vector for each of these things to be inputted into, and I have absolutely no idea how to do this. So, any assistance with which you could provide me would be greatly beneficial.

Thank you for your time and patience.

[image: Matlab Code]

Comment: No this will not work. Are you supposed to calculate numeric approximations to Gradient and Hessian or return the values after symbolic differentiation?

What do you expect "diff" to do? Have you checked by looking into the manual?

Comment: @gg no I’m supposed to calculate the actual gradient and the actual Hessian. Not approximations. I didn’t even know there was a manual. I just looked up online how to take partial derivatives in Matlab and tried to assign those values to the Hessian matrix and my gradient. Will the code not work simply because the way I’m calculating the gradient and the Hessian are wrong? How should I go about doing it then? There is a 100 point bounty on this because I expect that it’s going to require a lot of explaining to me. If you answered and explained the right way to do this, I’d give it to you.

Comment: @gg should I use these: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hessian.html instead?

Comment: @gg could you please tell me if the functions I linked in my last comment to you will work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Taking a symbolic processor we can build and generalize the tables for $\nabla f$ and $\nabla^2 f$

With MATHEMATICA we have for $n = 6$

```
n = 6;
X = Table[Subscript[x, k], {k, 1, 2 n}];
f = 1/2 Sum[k Subscript[x, k]^2, {k, 1, 2 n}] - Sum[Subscript[x, k], {k, 1, 2 n}] + Sum[1/4 (Subscript[x, k] + Subscript[x, k - 1])^2 + (Subscript[x, k] - Subscript[x, k - 1])^2, {k, 2, 2 n}] + (Subscript[x, 2 n] - Subscript[x, 1])^2;
grad = Grad[f, X];
H = Grad[grad, X];
MatrixForm[2 grad]
MatrixForm[2 H]
```

so we have

$$
\nabla f = \frac 12 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -3 x_2+11 x_1-4 x_{12}-2 \\
 -3 x_1+14 x_2-3 x_3-2 \\
 -3 x_2+16 x_3-3 x_4-2 \\
 -3 x_3+18 x_4-3 x_5-2 \\
 -3 x_4+20 x_5-3 x_6-2 \\
 -3 x_5+22 x_6-3 x_7-2 \\
 -3 x_6+24 x_7-3 x_8-2 \\
 -3 x_7+26 x_8-3 x_9-2 \\
 -3 x_8+28 x_9-3 x_{10}-2 \\
 -3 x_9+30 x_{10}-3 x_{11}-2 \\
 -3 x_{10}+32 x_{11}-3 x_{12}-2 \\
 -3 x_{11}+33 x_{12}-4 x_1-2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\nabla ^2 f = \frac 12\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 11 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
 -3 & 14 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 16 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 18 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 20 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 22 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 24 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 26 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 28 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 30 & -3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 32 & -3 \\
 -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 33 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Those tables can easily be generalized for any $n$ so in the programmed function those generalized tables can be directly inserted. As can be observed $H$ is a sparse diagonal dominant matrix that can be conveniently compacted before handling.

And for any $n$

$$
\nabla f = \frac 12 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -3 x_2+11 x_1-4 x_{2n}-2 \\
 -3 x_1+14 x_2-3 x_3-2 \\
 -3 x_2+16 x_3-3 x_4-2 \\
 -3 x_3+18 x_4-3 x_5-2 \\
 -3 x_4+20 x_5-3 x_6-2 \\
\vdots\\
 -3 x_{2n-4}+(2(2n-1)+11-4) x_{2n-3}-3 x_{2n-2}-2 \\
 -3 x_{2n-3}+(2(2n-1)+11-2) x_{10}-3 x_{2n-1}-2 \\
 -3 x_{2n-2}+(2(2n-1)+11-1) x_{2n-1}-3 x_{2n}-2 \\
 -3 x_{2n-1}+(2(2n-1)+11) x_{2n}-4 x_1-2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\nabla ^2 f = \frac 12\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 11 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
 -3 & 14 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 16 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 18 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 4n+6 & -3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 4n+8 & -3 \\
 -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 2(2n-1)+11 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

NOTE

The matlab function follows

```
function [val,g,H] = nTermSumFunction(x,n)
  g  = zeros(2*n,1);
  H  = zeros(2*n,2*n);
  k0 = 14;

  g(1)     =(-3*x(2)+11*x(1)-4*x(2*n)-2)/2;
  g(2*n)   =(-3*x(2*n-1)+(4*n+9)*x(2*n)-2)/2;
  H(1,1)   = 11/2; H(1,2) = -3/2; H(1,2*n) = -4/2;
  H(2*n,1) = -4/2; H(2*n,2*n-1) = -2/2;H(2*n,2*n) = (4*n+9)/2;
  val      = (x(2*n)-x(1))^2+1/2*x(1)^2-x(1);

  for k = 2:2*n-1
    val      = val + k/2*x(k)^2-x(k)+(x(k)+x(k-1))^2/4+(x(k)-x(k-1))^2;
    g(k)     = (-3*x(k-1)+k0*x(k)-3*x(k+1)-2)/2;
    H(k,k)   = k0/2;
    H(k,k+1) = -3/2;
    H(k,k-1) = -3/2;
    k0       = k0 + 2;
  end
```

Comment: I don’t even know what a symbolic processor is. Is the $f$ In your code the quadratic form the other person is mentioning in their answer?

Comment: The $f$ symbol corresponds to the quadratic function $f(x)$ in your question.

Comment: how did you figure out the pattern for the coefficients?

Comment: Attached the coefficient's table for a generic $n$

Comment: I like this solution. I just need to figure out how to translate what you did from Mathematica to Matlab. I like the way you generated the vector of x’s and then used that vector to take the gradients. I don’t know if any analogous tool exists in Matlab and my hands are tied as to which CAS I can use.

Comment: @ALannister Attached the matlab function implementation. Please check it. I am not a matlab expert.

Comment: @LinAlg I appreciate your concern but then I must be guilty of countless fouls! I try to teach what I know. If this is my fault, so sorry!

Comment: @Cesareo providing complete solutions is not considered teaching (except for some Asian countries)

Comment: @LinAlg a lot of people do learn by examples. That's basically how I taught myself calculus back in the day.

Comment: "I appreciate your concern but then I must be guilty of countless fouls!" Yes, you might be indeed! This is not the defence you seem to think it is.

Comment: ""I appreciate your concern but then I must be guilty of countless fouls!" Yes, you might be indeed! This is not the defence you seem to think it is." 
Apparently the inquisition did not disappear in the nineteenth century. Continue in some forums dedicated to teaching.

Comment: @Cesareo is this the gradient and the Hessian of the residuals?

Comment: @ALannister Those are the gradient and the hessian regarding $f(x)$

Comment: @Cesareo hmm...would I want it to be regarding $f(x)$ though if I wanted it to be an input function into code that finds the minimum of $f$ via the conjugate gradient method?

Comment: @ALannister For quadratic systems with a sparse hessian like the one focused in the question, is worth to use the conjugate gradient method. Please see at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#Example_code_in_MATLAB_/_GNU_Octave

Comment: @cesareo I have to use the conjugate gradient method. Are you saying that the way the hessian and gradient are defined in your answer is okay for that purpose or do I have to fine the hessian and gradient of the residuals like I do for Gauss-Newton?

Comment: @cesareo I mean from reading that article it looks like you’re supposed to use the true gradient and true Hessian of $f$, but not hearing somebody else who actually knows what they’re talking about actually say so is making me second-guess myself and giving me a lot of anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is based on symbolic math. There are two ways to move forward.

The first is to have continue with symbolic math and use automated differentiation. That will not be the fastest solution, because for $n=500$ you have roughly half a million elements in the Hessian you need to compute.

The second is to observe that your function is quadratic in $x$, and can be written as $0.5 x^TAx + b^Tx + c$. After computing $A$ and $b$, the gradient can be computed efficiently as $Ax+b$, and the Hessian is $A$.

Your objective function is:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(x_{i})^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}x_{i}+\sum_{i=2}^{2n}\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(x_{i}+x_{i-1} \right)^{2} +\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)^{2}\right]+\left(x_{2n}-x_{1} \right)^{2}. $$
The easiest way to set up your code is to initialize $A$ and $b$ to a matrix or vector with all zeros:

```
A = zeros(2*n,2*n);
b = zeros(2*n, 1);
```

and to go through the terms of $f$ and update $A$ and $b$. For example, the first
term affects the diagonal of $A$:

```
for i = 1:2*n
  A(i,i) = A(i,i) + i;
end
```

You should be able to figure out the code for the other terms. Note that you should compute $A$ and $b$ only once, not repeatedly in each iteration.

Comment: then $b$ should be a vector of $-1$’s?

Comment: @ALannister you are correct

Comment: I don’t think that C should consist of $$\sum_{i=2}^{2n}\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(x_{i}+x_{i-1} \right)^{2} +\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)^{2}\right]$$ because that is not constant in $x$

Comment: in order for what you said to be correct, you’re gonna need more matrices to take care of these terms but what these terms are is dynamic so I’m at a loss as to how to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @ALannister why would I need more matrices? Don't you agree that the objective is quadratic? And that every quadratic function can be written as $0.5 x^T A x + b^T x + c$? It seems like your problem is not with Matlab or with optimization.

Comment: or that I also have this problem in addition to those ;) so what you’re saying is that that above summation that starts at $n=2$ should also be included in the $A$ matrix?

Comment: Recognizing and utilizing the quadratic form is elegant. But maybe in this case it is more straightforward to just calculate gradient and Hessian from the function definition.

Comment: @gg I mean yeah maybe it will take more processing time. But if I change my code to use the functions I mention in my comments above to you, do you think it will work?

Comment: @LinAlg I see why you mean now, but figuring out how the other terms affect $A$ is giving me a headache. I’ve written out the quadratic for $n=1$ and now I’m writing it out for $n=2$ to see if I can find a pattern.

Comment: @ALannister you do not need to write anything out; term $i$ in the third summation affects elements $(i,i)$, $(i, i-1)$, $(i-1, i)$ and $(i-1, i-1)$ of $A$, so you can just put it in a for loop and perform those updates

Comment: @LinAlg after doing this, my goal is to have this matlab function be the input for another matlab function that does the conjugate gradient method to find the minimum value of my $f$. I shouldn’t have any issues with this, right?

Comment: @LinAlg also without expanding the third terms, how do I know how it is affecting those elements and what the updates should be?

Comment: @ALannister make sure you understand the relation between $A$ and the quadratic formula, e.g., via the examples in https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ash/LinearAlg/415Ch9.pdf